# How to center tabs with ngx-bootstrap

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

By default, tabs are displayed on the left, but you want them to be displayed in the center.
I would like to do the following.

```
<div>
  <tabset class="justify-content-center">
    <tab heading="Basic title" id="tab1">Basic content</tab>
    <tab heading="Basic Title 1">Basic content 1</tab>
    <tab heading="Basic Title 2">Basic content 2</tab>
  </tabset>
</div>
```

I looked at the tab page but it doesn't seem to support the center view, what should I do?
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/tabs

I tried to do the following in `styles.scss`, but I got a build error.

```
tabset ul {
  @extend .justify-content-center;
}
```

---

"ngx-bootstrap": "^5.2.0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting css like this, we were able to achieve what we wanted to do.

---

scss

```
.tabset-justify-content-center {
    .nav-tabs {
      @extend .justify-content-center;
  }
}

@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

html

```
<tabset class="tabset-justify-content-center">
```